# Why does this `using` block not release the database connection?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

Edit:
@Jeroen Mostert's comment worked well: adding `Pooling=false` to the connection string. As he/she noted, I have to read some more about this additions impact on overall performance.

- Lang: C#
- DBMS: Postgres

In the code below with two consecutive `using` blocks (much has been deleted to make it clear);

1. In the first `using` block, before dropping the database `camsdb`, I connect to the database for the last time and do a final query.
2. After the query, the code exits the first `using` block and is supposed to close the database connection.
3. Unfortunately, the second `using` block (which is supposed to drop the database that was just connected to in the first using block) fails to drop the database. The `PostgresException` says "There is 1 other session using the database."

However, when I comment out the first `using` block, the second `using` block —fulfilling its duty— drops the database without any problem. Isn't that using block supposed to close the connection when the code reaches the related curly brace? Is there a way to force the Garbage Collector to clean the connection immediately? (Any other solutions are welcome.)

```
private M_SqlConn m_sqlConn = null; // predefined
...
...

// *** using block no: 1 ***
using (m_sqlConn = new M_SqlConn("127.0.0.1", 5432, "camsdb", "my_user_name", "my_password")) {
    // perform a last sql query
}

// *** using block no: 2 ***
using (m_sqlConn = new M_SqlConn("127.0.0.1", 5432, "postgres", "postgres", "admin_password")) {
    if (this.DbDrop("camsdb")) {
        FormWarn_ShowDialog(FormWarn.FormType.Info, "db dropped succesfully ...")
    }
    else {
        FormWarn_ShowDialog(FormWarn.FormType.Error, "can not drop db !!!")
    }
}
```

The `M_SqlConn` class as a whole is below (didn't want to mess up the page, that's why I didn't paste it at first):

```
using Npgsql;
using System;
using System.Text;

internal class M_SqlConn : IDisposable {
    public Boolean connectionIsOpen = false;
    private FormWarn formWarn = null;
    private NpgsqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
    private String hostAddress = "";
    private String portNumber = "";
    private String dbName = "";
    private String roleName = "";
    private String password = "";

    internal M_SqlConn(String hostAddress, String portNumber, String dbName, String roleName, String password) {
        this.hostAddress = hostAddress;
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
        this.dbName = dbName;
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.password = password;
        this.ConnectionOpen();
        return;
    }

    private void ConnectionOpen() {
        StringBuilder exceptionString = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);
        NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder {
            Host = this.hostAddress,
            Port = Convert.ToInt32(this.portNumber),
            Database = this.dbName,
            Username = this.roleName
        };

        this.sqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString() + $";Password={this.password}");

        try {
            this.sqlConnection.Open();

            if (this.sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) {
                this.connectionIsOpen = true;
            }
        }
        catch (PostgresException e) {
            exceptionString.AppendLine(
                $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Postgres Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
        catch (NpgsqlException e) {
            exceptionString.AppendLine(
                $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Npgsql Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            exceptionString.AppendLine(
                $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"General Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }

        if (!this.connectionIsOpen) {
            this.FormWarn_ShowDialog(FormWarn.FormType.Error, exceptionString.ToString());
        }

        return;
    }

    private void ConnectionClose() {
        StringBuilder exceptionString = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);

        if (this.sqlConnection != null) {
            try {
                this.sqlConnection.Close();
                this.connectionIsOpen = false;
            }
            catch (PostgresException e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Postgres Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Npgsql Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"General Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }

            if (this.connectionIsOpen) {
                this.FormWarn_ShowDialog(FormWarn.FormType.Error, exceptionString.ToString());
            }
            else {
                this.sqlConnection.Dispose();
                this.sqlConnection = null;
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    public Boolean SqlCommandExecuteNonQuery(String sqlString) {
        Boolean commandStatus = false;
        StringBuilder exceptionString = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);

        using (NpgsqlCommand sqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlString, this.sqlConnection)) {
            try {
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                commandStatus = true;
            }
            catch (PostgresException e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Postgres Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Npgsql Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"General Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
        };

        if (!commandStatus) { 
            exceptionString.AppendLine(
                $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Sql string is:{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"{sqlString}{Environment.NewLine}");
            this.FormWarn_ShowDialog(FormWarn.FormType.Error, exceptionString.ToString());
        }

        return (commandStatus);
    }

    public Int32 SqlCommandExecuteScalar(String sqlString) {
        Int32 count = -1;
        StringBuilder exceptionString = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);

        using (NpgsqlCommand sqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlString, this.sqlConnection)) {
            try {
                Int32 countTmp = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
                count = countTmp;
            }
            catch (PostgresException e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Postgres Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Npgsql Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"General Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
        };

        if (count == -1) {
            exceptionString.AppendLine(
                $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Sql string is:{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"{sqlString}{Environment.NewLine}");
            this.FormWarn_ShowDialog(FormWarn.FormType.Error, exceptionString.ToString());
        }

        return (count);
    }

    public NpgsqlDataReader SqlCommandExecuteQuery(String sqlString) {
        NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = null;
        StringBuilder exceptionString = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);

        using (NpgsqlCommand sqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlString, this.sqlConnection)) {
            try {
                dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (PostgresException e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Postgres Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Npgsql Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                exceptionString.AppendLine(
                    $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"General Exception{Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"{e.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
        };

        if (exceptionString.Length > 0) {
            exceptionString.AppendLine(
                $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Sql string is:{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"{sqlString}{Environment.NewLine}");
            this.FormWarn_ShowDialog(FormWarn.FormType.Error, exceptionString.ToString());
        }

        return (dataReader);
    }

    private void FormWarn_ShowDialog(FormWarn.FormType formType, String msg) {
        using (this.formWarn = new FormWarn(formType, msg)) {
            this.formWarn.ShowDialog();
        }

        this.formWarn.Dispose();
        this.formWarn = null;
        return;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (this.formWarn != null) {
            this.formWarn.Dispose();
            this.formWarn = null;
        }

        if (this.connectionIsOpen) {
            this.ConnectionClose();
        }

        this.hostAddress = "";
        this.portNumber = "";
        this.dbName = "";
        this.roleName = "";
        this.password = "";
        return;
    }
}
```

I've tried @Panagiotis's trick but it didn't work. Changed the `if` block to the below but this time the program halted giving "*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*"

```
if (this.sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) {
    this.sqlConnection.Dispose(); // exception here
    this.sqlConnection = null;
}
```

Comment: What is `M_SqlConn`? That's not a standard type.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: That's my class which is used creating a connection.

Comment: Could you show this class? Are you write code to close connection in Dispose method?

Comment: The garbage collector is not the problem, incidentally. It's either your own `Dispose` logic, or else the Postgres database provider keeps the (physical) connection pooled. There are typically ways to turn that off for a specific connection, but that depends on the connection library used. (Clearing the connection pool is another approach, but that's a global solution to a local problem.)

Comment: It's `M_SqlConn`'s job to close the connection when exiting the using block. Most likely though, that class isn't needed. ADO.NET provides database object factories since 2006. You can even [pick provider factories by name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory) and get a factory already configured with the connection string, credentials etc

Comment: Once you have a DbProviderFactory, just [ask it for a DbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory#creating-the-dbproviderfactory-and-dbconnection) or DbCommand object and the rest is generic ADO.NET code

Comment: Now that you posted the code, *you don't call sqlConnection.Close* at all. You should *call sqlConnection.Dispose()* whether it's open or not. It's the *connection's* job to check and take care of its status. *All* tutorials and examples show using a connection inside a `using` block, so not only *can* you use `Dispose()` on it, it's the only thing guaranteed to always work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'll give it a try.

Comment: It's a common misconception that setting fields and variables to `null` explicitly does something special (like making it "easier" for the garbage collector to clean up things). This is largely unnecessary, and in the rare cases where it is necessary (like preventing event handlers from keeping an object alive) it's more involved than just setting a local field to a `null`. You're best off unlearning this habit. On the other hand, consistently using `using` and avoiding wrappers for disposable objects are both good habits.

Comment: In the same vein: `using` has a built-in `null` check, so either `using (this.SqlConnection) {}` or (in more recent versions of C#) `this.SqlConnection?.Dispose()` (using null propagation) would suffice to unconditionally dispose. Do not perform state checks to see if you "should" dispose.

Comment: When this.DbDrop returns false, is it possible to query your postgres database and see where the open connection(s) is/are?  Something like: select *
from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'mydatabasename';

Comment: It doesn't matter what `ConnectionClose` does - don't call it when disposing. Just call `.Dispose()`. This way you avoid any bugs that would prevent proper disposal

Comment: `NpgSqlConnection` supports connection pooling; if the "open session" persists despite disposing everything, create a non-pooled connection by passing `Pooling = false` to the connection string builder *for that connection only*. Take care not to make this a global default, as that would negatively impact performance for most applications.

Comment: In addition to everything else said about the lack of necessity for this wrapper class of yours, the only API you offer your other code is to pass a single string for the query; Meaning callers can't parameterize their queries, leaving you wide open to SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Oppps, You got it! Adding `Pooling=false` worked.

Comment: As written above, Npgsql provides connection pooling by default, as is standard for ADO.NET providers. In other words, closing or disposing NpgsqlConnection won't actually close the physical connection, just return it to the pool.

Comment: One way to solve this without disabling pooling (which can have a profound impact on performance), is to disallow all new connections, and then forcefully terminate all existing connections (`REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE <database> FROM PUBLIC; SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = '<database>'`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling dispose for your sqlConnection.
please uncomment this.

```
this.sqlConnection.Dispose();
```

And remove the calling of your method CloseConnection();

As you can see here https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/01f3f97bf7500229f896fda1f56279da78894d12/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnection.cs

NpgsqlConnection is IDisposable. And when you call Dispose for it, it should run all logic and close the connection. It is not correct to write a Wrapper that will call Close for it. When you do this it can have a random behavior.

One question, if NpgsqlConnection is IDisposable from the box, are you really needing your OWN class that is a Wrapper (or Proxy) in nature?

Comment: I've pasted the `ConnectionClose` method.

Comment: Update my answer

Comment: @ssd just *don't* use that method. Use `Dispose()` instead. There's no reason to perform the same checks that `Dispose()` does.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos & TemaTre: Let me try that way. I'll let you know.

Comment: Nope! Same problem persists though I've commented the whole `if` block and left the `Close` connection duty solely to Npgsql.

Comment: Are you uncomment this.sqlConnection.Dispose();?

Comment: Yes, I've commented the `this.sqlConnection.Dispose()` line and let the Npgsql do all the closing work for me but got the same exception. (see my last edit at the top of the question)

Comment: Excuse me, why you comented line? You should UNcoment it.

Comment: @TemaTre: Tried both ways; commented & then un-commented. Didn't work either way.

Answer (score 2):

You, for sure, already know it but let's settle some concepts.

**What `using` means in C#?**
It means if the class implements `IDisposable`, the `Dispose()` method will be called at the end fo the Object instance life-cycle.

**Who opens and close the connection?**
The library does it. You merely call some method of an instance of some class exposed by the library and hopes it does the job for you.

**Why are connections kept?**
Most times you do want to reuse the same connection with your app, and most times that's great since each connection consumes resources.
That's why we have connections pools.

**What can you do to mitigate your problem?**
You can try another library as suggested in the comments.
Or see **TemaTre answer** she/he looks like to have a good insight into that specific library.

But also note you are doing something unusual.
You do have two connections (and two connection pools?).
One for a "normal" user to query the database.
A second conn for an admin to drop the database.

I can suggest you to first put the database in **single-user mode** and to be sure there are no other connections to it, even connections external to your application. You can achieve it by using simple SQL commands before dropping the DB.